# A couple of questions regarding on OO and library design

Tags: c#, oop, library-design

Ok. I have some questions regarding to some aspects of OO, and library design.

1. Should a library be self-sufficient? Eg., can it use an external Dependency Injection framework, or should it implement it own, in a more lightweight manner?
2. How does the Liskov's Substitution Principle fits on polymorphism, where you *don't* know the behavior of a method or class? You just expect it to work like it should?
3. On the source code part, is a bad habit keep the interfaces on a separated folder (eg., `/interfaces`) from their implementation?
4. It's also a bad habit delimit generic types (`where T : type`) on interfaces rather than just in their implementations? (this one I don't think so, but it's just to confirm it).
5. Is an interface favorable over a abstract class when the object relationship is both, "can do" and "is a", and there's no need of a default implementation for methods and etc?

That's it. Thanks for your time =)

Comment: Seems like these are different enough that they could each have their own StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Should a library be self-sufficient?**

Libraries can surely use, for example, Dependency Injection frameworks. However, it is [debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1831455/146622) whether you want to force the DI framework upon the user of the library.

**2. How does the Liskov's Substitution Principle fit on polymorphism?**

Liskov's Substitution Principle is about being able to interchange one implementation with another (substitution), and *regardless of the behavior*, there should be no errors when the user adheres to the contract. For example, swapping a `CanonPrinter` for an `EpsonPrinter` should still allow you to print if you use just the methods from the `Printer` class. Calling something `Printer` but having a particular implementation (Canon, Epson) underlying it is polymorphism.

**3. Is it a bad habit to keep the interfaces in a folder separate from their implementation?**

It is a personal preference whether you'll want to keep interfaces apart from their implementation. I don't do it; I don't even have an interface for each implementation. I think it only makes sense to have an interface for an implementation if it adds value to your project.

**4. Is it also a bad habit to limit generic types on interfaces rather than just in their implementations?**

If you think a generic type should be limited to a particular type, then you should do that where it makes sense (so, this may be on the interface). For example, having a `IPrintableDocument<TPrinter>` and not limiting `TPrinter` to `Printer` objects would *not* make sense, so I'd do it.

**5. Is an interface favorable over an abstract class when the object relationship is both "can do" and "is a"?**

Indeed, most people use abstract classes for *is a* and interfaces for *can do* relations. The reason: a class can inherit from only one base class but from multiple interfaces. In essence, this means that a class *can be* only one thing (a `Employee` *is a* `Person`) but *can do* multiple (it might `ICopyDocuments`, `IWalkAbout`, `IMakeCoffee`). Whatever you do when an interface is both depends on your preferences.

---

Most of your questions have to do with the *contract* of a class (or interface): the contract specifies what a user (another class, someone else's code) *can do* and *cannot do* with the class and its members, and it specifies what the user may expect the class *will do* and *will not do*.

For example: the user *can* only pass objects as arguments to a method when they match the parameter type. The class *will* only return objects as return values that match the return type. A user *can* only call members defined in the class, and the class *will* make sure those methods behave according to the contract (i.e. not throwing errors, no side effects, never returning null).

Generic type constraints are also part of the contract. I even consider the documentation part of the contract: when it states that a method *will never* throw an exception, then no implementation should ever throw an exception. There is no syntax or compiler rule enforcing it, but it is part of the contract. Some parts of the contract are enforced by the compiler or the runtime, others are not.

When a class or interface has a particular contract, then any subclass or implementation can be substituted for it and it will still work *when that subclass or implementation adheres to the contract*. If it adheres to the contract, then that's Liskov's Substitution Principle (LSP). And it is easily to deviate from it, and many programmers do. Sometimes you have no choice.

A clear example of a violation of the LSP in the .NET Framework is the [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). It implements the [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) interface but has no actual implementation for many of its methods. So if you pass a user expecting a `IList<T>` a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and the user tries to call `list.Add`, then an exception will be thrown. So, you cannot always substitute `IList<T>` for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so it violates the LSP.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer these in order:

1. It depends.  Taking on an external dependency potentially limits the usefulness and scope of your library, as it will only be usable in situations where that dependency is available.  This may be fine, however, and preferential to trying to work around the dependency.  If you know the users of your library will always be using a specific DI framework, I'd build the library around it instead of implementing something that will need "adapting" to work.
2. "where you don't know the behavior of a method or class?" You should know the contract of any types you are using.  LSP basically says that, no matter what *concrete* type you get, the base class/interface contract will always be valid.  This means you can just "use the type" and expect it to work.
3. No - but this is a private implementation detail.  It is typically a bad idea to separate out the *namespaces*, however, and it's often nice to keep the source code tree matching the namespaces.
4. No.  If an interface is really intended to only be used with a specific type, it should have the contraints on the interface.
5. In general, a single contract should only provide one aspect of the relationship.  If the contract suggests "is-a" **and** "can-do", it likely should be split into two contracts, perhaps an abstract class which implements the "can-do" interface.

Comment: on #3 - isn't there sometimes a big advantage to separating (at the project/library level) interfaces from concrete implementations? For example in repositories?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Typically you will prefix an interface with `I` to differenciate it.  If everything is in the same namespace or folder structure, you won't have to worry about collisions with the prefixed `I`.  This also helps when casting to an interface as you wont have to have another `using` to do the cast. (assuming you would have a different namespace for a different folder)

Comment: @Matthew - I'm not talking about naming collisions, i'm talking about programming to an interface, hiding implementation, mocking, test-ability, etc.

Comment: But thinking now, there'll be another level of directories and sub-directories, separating each part of the library, thus making more viable and organized put them in the same directory as their implementation, am I right?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Yes, but not in the public API.  Publicly visible types that correspond with the interfaces shouldn't be separated.  Basically, I wouldn't blatantly separate interfaces out just to separate them from implementations.  There are times when it makes sense to not have any concrete implementations public, but that's kind of a separate issue.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin IMO - Separating interfaces should be done deliberately based on the usage, but not based on separating purely to keep "interfaces separate" in the file system.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - very good point about avoiding separation in the public API, I didn't think of that at first. Also, agree that it should only be done for a specific and worth while reason. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at 5.

The only difference between an abstract class and an interface is that an abstract class can have class variables. I would choose an interface if the abstract class is only composed of viratual methods.

Comment: The abstract class can also have method implementations (virtual and non-virtual) and static members...

Answer (score 0):

On #1 - http://jeviathon.com/2012/03/05/roll-your-own-syndrome/

Basically, the point is, why "roll your own" xyz framework when someone has likely already  created robust, tested and supported software which does the same thing.

Spend your time researching picking the "right" external libraries and frameworks to use, not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

1. "It depends". But there's little value in reinventing your own wheel, especially in so populated (and hard to implement) areas as DI and ORM. And especially when you can (a) bin-deploy your dependencies or (b) specify your dependencies as nuget packages, if your library is nuget package (as it of course should be)
2. LSP has little relation to polymorphism. It states that class (or method) should behave according to contract, and that is, in fact, the only thing that you do know about implementor's behavior.
3. Folders should correspond to namespaces. Do you put interfaces in separate namespace? I do not, and I don't think anybody should. And when I have interface with only one implementation (e.g., unit-testing-induced), I prefer to keep in in one file with its implementation.
4. No, it's not. Why should it be?
5. If there's no need for default implementation, got for an interface. Interface is easier to mock and also easier to implement, because it doesn't mess with your implementation's inheritance. In fact, you can even implement several interfaces on one class, if that somehow highlights your intent (for example, if you have specific service dealing with security, it is not uncommon for it to implement both `IAuthentication` and `IAuthorization`). Lately I choose abstract classes only when there's a clear need for them.